# CSS Background-position not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, background-image, background-position

I'm having a problem positioning a background image properly. It works on desktop, and even when I resize the window to simulate a phone it displays correctly, but when I actually visit the website on my phone (tested on Android/Chrome and iOS/Safari) it seems to be ignoring the background-position property.

CSS in question:

```
.blur {
        background: 
    /* top, transparent blue, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1), 
        rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    /* BACKGROUND IMAGE */
    url('https://suzannecowan.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2015-10-20-macleans-2-1.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: -350px -150px;
  background-position-x: -350px;
  background-position-y: -150px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {

.blur {
      background: 
    /* top, transparent blue, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1), 
      rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    /* BACKGROUND IMAGE */
    url('https://suzannecowan.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2015-10-20-macleans-2-1.jpg');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: -350px 0; 
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  }

@media (min-width: 50em) {

  .blur {
  background: 
      /* top, transparent blue, faked with gradient */ 
      linear-gradient(to right,
        rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1), 
        rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.1)
      ),
      /* bottom, image */
      /* BACKGROUND IMAGE */
      url('https://suzannecowan.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2015-10-20-macleans-2-1.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: -250px 0; 
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: none;
    }
```

I've searched for solutions and found two suggestions that have helped people it the past: adding `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` which didn't help, and moving the background image out of `body` and into a different container (`.blur` in this case) which also didn't help.

The website is: https://suzannecowan.ca/.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Have you tried using a pixel amount for `@media (min-width: )`? I have never seen `em` used for that purpose.

Comment: @theblindprophet I've always used `em` for it and never had a problem before, but I changed it as you suggested and it made no difference.

Comment: What's especially frustrating is that I used the same technique on shaun-francis.com and it worked perfectly, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong now.

Comment: I don't know if you're into the extra work factor, but I have a resource that works 100% : https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Comment: why u used background-size property?

Comment: remove background-size: cover property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting your bg image to `cover` means that it will want to stretch to the height of the screen, which means on a small device that you'll get a very narrow view of it. Personally, I'd either resize the image to be taller and thinner so that it fits better on a mobile screen, or instead set the background size to `100% auto`, which looks pretty good imho.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I changed the background size and removed the background positioning for mobile only and it works fine. Good to note that this solution wouldn't work if I needed the background image to fill the whole screen (which is why I was using `cover`), but because in this case it doesn't matter if the picture doesn't fill the whole screen lengthwise, this solution will work.

Comment: Cool. I also just read today that "you cannot use background-attachment fixed and background-size:cover together in ios as the image will stretch to the whole content and not just the viewport (it's a long standing issue with ios)." So you were also working against an actual bug there.

Answer (score 0):

In Android/Chrome, the background IS being positioned. If you change the value it moves the image. You can also confirm it through the Chrome (mobile) web debugger.

The difference between mobile/desktop comes from the difference in how the two treat those length units.